# Laravel ошибка при добавлении в БД

Tags: php, sql, laravel

При добавлении в БД возникает ошибка

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'age' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `items` () values ())

В protected $fillable в модели все необходимые поля есть. Код контроллера ниже:

```
public function postAdd(Request $request){
    dump($request->all());
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        ]);
    $girl_data = $request->all();
    $item = new Item;
    $item->save();

}
```

Метод dump показывает, что в модель записываются все значения из полей формы. Но если, например, использовать настройку 'strict' => true, в config.php, то ошибки не возникает, но в таблицу записывается строка с нулями.
Хотелось бы разобраться.

Comment: Извиняюсь, при настройке 'strict' => false падают нули.

Comment: Добавьте данные `age` или установите в бд дефолтное значение.

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто! При создании новой записи в таблицу БД необходимо заполнять все значения имеющиеся у этой таблицы столбцов, кроме тех которые присваиваются автоматически или имеют значения по умолчанию Пример:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->default('1');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('old_price');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

1) Здесь значения полей `($table->bigIncrements('id');)` и `($table->timestamps();)` вставляются автоматически.

2) Значения полей `($table->string('name');)` и  `($table->integer('old_price');)` необходимо вставлять обязательно.

3) А Значение поля `($table->integer('user_id')->default('1');)` вставлять необязательно т.к. оно имеет значение по умолчанию `(->default('1'))` и если его забыть прописать оно будет равно единице!
Конкретно Ваша ошибка говорит о том что поле `"age"` не заполнено и не имеет значений по умолчанию.